# при ошибке named router outlet Angular не выкидывает на 404

Tags: angular, angular-routing

при добавлении в `url/(ANY)`

- http://localhost:4200/tasks/**(x)**
- http://localhost:4200/tasks/**(212asdasd)**
- http://localhost:4200/tasks **(a)**
- http://localhost:4200/tasks **(adsasdasd)**

Вылетает ошибка `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'adsasdasd'`
Но должно было отправить на 404 страницу и сейчас всё приложение падает

Я так понимаю, что из-за функционала именованного роутинга Angular пытается его найти
Как можно правильно отловить такой кейс или обработать ?

```
{ path: '404', component: NotFoundPageComponent, canActivate: [HttpStatusCodeGuard], data: { httpStatusCode: 404 } },
{ path: '**', component: NotFoundPageComponent, canActivate: [HttpStatusCodeGuard], data: { httpStatusCode: 404 } }
```

Пример:
В Angular.io https://angular.io/guide/component-styles(2) будет редирект на 404
В Angular Material https://material.angular.io/cdk/categories(2) страница упадёт

Временно обхожу эту проблему сервисом, который вызывается в конструкторе app-routing.module.ts

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationError, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UntilDestroy, untilDestroyed } from '@ngneat/until-destroy';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@UntilDestroy()
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoutingErrorHandlerService {
  public wasHandled: boolean = false;

  constructor(private readonly _router: Router, private location: Location) { }

  public init(): void {
    this._router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationError && !this.wasHandled),
      map((error: NavigationError) => error),
      map((error) => error.url.replace('undefined:', '')),
      untilDestroyed(this)
    ).subscribe((url) => {
      this.wasHandled = true;
      this._router.navigate(['/404']).then(() => this.location.replaceState((url)));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: canActivate: [HttpStatusCodeGuard] - вот это условие мешает

Comment: пробовал убрать canActivate, результат прежний